# Force Chef to run recipes multiple times with different attributes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe

I have a cookbook (CB1) with a recipe (`install_app`) that will install applications. `install_app` actually executes a series of other recipes in CB1 and it uses attributes to change which application your installing and the application's settings.

I have recipes for each application that sets CB1 attributes and then they each call `include_recipe CB1::install_app`.

But it seems this does not work. Chef compiles all the recipes in the run list first and then executes them so only the first call to `include_recipe CB1::install_app` executes.

How do I force Chef to run the recipes multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible, recipes are considered to be singletons. What you want is to make a custom resource instead. Then you can invoke that resource multiple times with different inputs (properties).

Comment: Arg the only way is making this a LWRP? Is there a way to force chef to do this? I saw something called include_recipe_now that looks like it might do what I want.

Comment: No, the `now` cookbook is for messing with compile vs. converge stuffs, very much not what you want. Technically this is possible but it breaks all kinds of stuff to a degree that I'm not going to tell you how :P Take your existing recipe code and paste it into the action block of a custom resource, shouldn't be all that difficult. Then replace anything that needs to vary with properties (i.e. `node['foo']` -> `new_resource.foo` and add `property :foo` at the top of the file). Then make a new recipe file to call your custom resource a bunch of times with node attrs as inputs.

Comment: Can I use definitions for this? From what I'm reading "A definition will create a wrapper that groups one or more other resources together". Seems like they also serve this purpose? Advantages of one over the other? Definitions look like they are simpler.

Comment: Definitions used to be simpler in days long past, at this point there is no reason to use them :) check out the new 12.5 syntax for custom resources, it's super easy